# Adding an Objective-C++ file to a C++ Xcode 5 project

Tags: xcode, xcode5, llvm

I am attempting to add an ObjC++ file to a large Xcode 5 C++ project.

For legacy reasons, the "Compile Sources As" setting must remain "C++". If I could change this setting to "According to File Type" the ObjC++ file would build properly, but it won't compile if Xcode thinks its a C++ file.

I have tried explicitly setting the Type of the .mm file under Identity and Type to "Objective-C++ Source" and the compiler still attempts to build it as a C++ file. I have tried adding the "-ObjC" and "-ObjC++" compiler flags to to the individual file under Build Phases > Compile Sources, and I get a warning that the argument is unused during compilation.

I have tried this process in reverse, adding an ObjC++ file to a different project that is compiling sources as "According to File Type," and setting the Type to C++. As expected, the file fails to build. This shows that specifying the type of an individual file takes precedence over the project setting.

Is there no way to force Xcode5.1.1/llvm5.1 to build a single ObjC++ or ObjC file as the correct type? The project setting is overridden by the individual file setting in every case I've tested, except trying to build an ObjC++ file. Is this a bug or missing feature?

Comment: Why don't you use a real build system like CMake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close with the ObjC++ flag.

Set the file's Compiler Flags in the Compile Sources Build Phase to `-x objective-c++ $(inherited)`.